# ASP.NET MVC Remote Validation logic on Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model and an actionMethod in MVC;

```
public class employee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string employeeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("doesCnicExist", "employee", AdditionalFields = "employeeID", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "A user with this cnic already exists. Please enter a different cnic.")]
    public string cnic { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesCnicExist(string employeeID, string cnic)
    {
        var empList = hc.employee.ToList();
        bool flag = false;
        foreach (employee e in empList)
        {
            if ((employeeID == e.employeeID) && (cnic == e.cnic))
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return Json(flag == false);
    }
```

On `Create()` action, it works great. But on `Edit()` action, program sees `cnic` already exist. And I cannot update `employee` with the same `cnic`. I cannot figure out how I can use additional `employeeID` field to achieve uniquness of employee object while editing?

Comment: What is the difference between `int id` and `string employeeID`? And you need to show the `doesCnicExist()` method you have tried.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `int id` is autogenrated by the database for the table and `Employee ID` is assigned by the organization. I am sorry I have been totally unable to think about a possible logic for this situation - for `doesCnicExist()`. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: But you said it works for your `Create()` action. So show it and then it can be corrected to work for the `Edit()` method. (Bu as far as the `id` and `employeeID ` fields go, what is the point of having 2 identifier fields? - you should be using the `id` field in `AdditionalFields` since that's the key)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got your point. But what difference it makes, since id will also always exist while editing. I have uploaded `doesCnicExist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `id` is your unique identifier, you need to pass that to the `doesCnicExist()` method and then you can modify the logic to ignore exiting rows where the `id` already exists. Change the model to

```
public class employee
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    ....
    [Required]
    [Remote("doesCnicExist", "employee", AdditionalFields = "id", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "A user with this cnic already exists. Please enter a different cnic.")]
    public string cnic { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesCnicExist(string cnic, int id)
{
    return Json(IsUnique(cnic, id));
}

private bool IsUnique(string cnic, int id)
{
  if (id == 0) // its a new object
  {
    return !hc.employee.Any(x => x.cnic == cnic);
  }
  else // its an existing object so exclude existing objects with the id
  {
    return !hc.employee.Any(x => x.cnic == cnic && x.id != id);
  }
}
```

Note that I have separated the logic into a separate method because `RemoteAttribute` is client side validation only and validation should always be performed on the server (client side validation should be considered a nice bonus, but a malicious user can easily bypass it). The separate method also allows you to validate it in the `Create()` and `Edit()` POST methods to prevent a possible exception being thrown when you save to the database.

But because `RemoteAttribute` is a client side (UI) attribute, it should not be applied to a data model anyway, and you should be following best practice and using a [view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) where the attribute is applied to your view model property and not the data model. I also recommend you use normal naming conventions for your classes and property names (i.e. PascalCase).

Comment: Side note: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jVHK7p) for an example of how it works

Comment: After your suggested solution, I am sorry but `[HttpPost] Create()` is not firing. When I press `Create` button, program just jams there.

Comment: What do you mean - nothing in my code has anything to do with your `Create()` method - you have not even shown it in your question

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have not included a hidden input for the `id` property in your create view so therefore the value of `id` is `null` which would result in an exception. If that is the case, make the parameter nullable - `doesCnicExist(string cnic, int? id)`

Comment: And ditto for `IsUnique(string cnic, int? id)`. Then change the code in the `IsUnique()` method to `if (!d.HasValue)` and `return !hc.employee.Any(x => x.cnic == cnic && x.id != id.Value);`

Comment: Yes indeed, hidden input property for `id` was not included. So when I changed `IsUnique(string cnic, int id)` to `IsUnique(string cnic, int? id)`, it started working like a charm. Thank You.  :)

Comment: Just as a side note. Not sure if you know linq very well but your current `foreach` loop is awful in terms of performance. Imagine you had 100,000 employees. Your code first gets all of them from the database and adds then to an in-memory collection. Then you loop through them and assuming you find a match after the 10th iteration you still continue to loop through all the remaining 99,990 items. Compare that with using `.Any()` which does it without reading anything into memory and it stops searching as soon as it finds a match.